# Finding the time from disance and speed

Tags: arithmetic

$2$ bikes $A$ and $B$ took part in a $1.5$ km Race. $A$ travel at $100$ km/h. $B$ travel at $120$ km/h. After how many minutes/seconds Bike $A$ will reach finishing point after Bike $B$ finishes?

--the answer is given as $3$ minutes or$0.05$ hours.  I am unable to get this answer.  Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Three minutes is $.05$ of an hour, not $.005$.  As the bikes each go well over a kilometer in a minute, the proposed answer of three minutes is obviously wrong.

Comment: You have problem with answer only. Or problem in solving?

Comment: I am not able to get 3 minutes

Comment: Answer is 9 seconds according to this question. Maybe you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that $\textrm{time}\times\textrm{rate}=\textrm{distance}$, so this means that $\textrm{time} = \textrm{distance}\div\textrm{rate}$.

This will let you compute a time for each biker. Assuming they started at the same instant, you can find the difference in their times by just subtracting.

Don't forget to convert the times to the same units for computation.

Comment: I am getting A - 54 sec and B- 45 sec....

Answer (score 0):

Since $distance=rate*time$, $time=distance*\frac{1}{rate}$.

So the time it takes $A$ to complete the race is $1.5\ Km*\frac{1hr}{100Km}=.015\ hours$.

Similarly, the time it takes $B$ is $1.5\ Km*\frac{1hr}{120Km}=.0125\ hours$.

Consequently, $A$ arrives $.015-.0125=.0025 \ hours$ later.

$.0025\ hours *\frac{60\ min}{1\ hour}*\frac{60\ seconds}{1\ min}=9\ seconds$.

Answer (score 0):

$Time$ = $\frac{Distance}{Speed}$

For biker A Time = $\frac{1.5}{100}$ = $.015$ hours or $54$ sec.

For biker B Time = $\frac{1.5}{120}$ = $.0125$ hours or $45$ sec.

So difference is $9$ sec.